# Extract filename from path using perl (IE8 browser)

Tags: perl, internet-explorer-8

I am working with perl to upload a file to the server and then parse it to get information out of it. The page is in cgi script, and I am using the perl module

```
use File::Basename;
```

my server side code is:

```
my $path = $cgi->param('filename');
my $filename = basename($path);
if ($filename) {
  if ($filename =~ /.csv/i) {do nothing;}
  else {
    $error = 'please upload a csv file';
    push @error, $error;
  }
}
```

I have tried everything, the codes runs fine on Chrome, Safari, Firefox but when I test it on IE8. The file name changes to the complete path name. So for example C:/meetup/sf/perl.csv is the complete path. In CSF the file name shows up as perl.csv but in IE8: it shows up as C:/meetup/sf/perl.csv

Can someone help me to figure out the correct way to get the file name so that it shows up correctly in all the browsers.

Thanks,
Parik

Comment: `/.csz/i` should be `/\.csz\z/i`, and I don't see why you can't use it even when you have a complete path.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/Path%3a%3aClass), which is explicitly for cross-platform path handling.

```
use Path::Class 'file';
my $filename = file($path)->basename;
```

Comment: steveni, the server that I am using is Sun and the perl version is 5.8.4. when I am using the code above it gives me Can't locate Path/Class.pm in @INC error. Do I need to install this package separately?

Comment: Yes, that's not a core module. If it's a problem to install that, also try [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec)->splitpath(), which Path::Class uses internally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the unix / windows path delimiter. instead of the usual / to separate the components IE8 is passing probably passing it in as \.

You might be able to achieve an universal solution by doing something like this:

```
    my $path = $cgi->param('filename');
    # replace all occurences of \ with / chrome/firefox etc won't be affected 
    #because they wont have any \ delimiters
    $path =~ s/\\/\//g;  

    my ($name,$parsed_path,$suffix) = fileparse($path,@suffixlist);
    print "name $name \n"; # this should carry the name of the file eg perl.csv
```

Comment: I did use the same thing, to replace all the delimiters to a common std, but still the same issue!

Comment: Hi Parik have you printed $path straight after you get it from #cgi->param ? See what the filename actually contains and also compare this versus what Chrome/Firefox return in the filename.